# Generalizing Solr suggestions

Tags: solr

I am trying to set up search suggestions for an e-commerce site, I have set up the suggest handler and it works, to an extent...

My issue lies in the suggestions it returns, it is giving full product titles (such as "The Division 2 PS4 Game") but I'm looking for more general terms (such as "The division 2") Is this something I can do using the suggest component?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you typing?what is term for the suggestion? What data you have indexing?

Comment: You'll have to index a separate field with that term in that case - transforming the value before indexing it into a new field based on a set of rules that you create in your indexing pipeline. There is nothing automagic you can enable that will do it for you, as the rules will differ for most use cases.